# Access SQL: like function on a number field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have ,for example, this table in a Microsoft Access database:

```
id                        numeric
context                   text
numberfield               numeric
```

I want to select every record that ends with 9 in the column"numberfield". This gives a problem because it is a numeric field and as a result I can not use the following SQL:

```
select * from table where numberfield like "%9"
```

A solution is that I change the numberfield to a text. But this gives a problem because there are several users and the change might give a problem in the future. Is there an option to select on the ending when it is a number field?

Comment: You can't use that SQL?  You could in most databases.  In any case, just convert the number to a string.

Comment: Yhea i also thought it was possible. I usually use postgres. But i can't change the number to string. This is due the fact that there are mutiple users and might ruin the database by filling the column with text( and not a number(there are always those people))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sound a little fishy.. are you sure you can use that query? Don't know about Access but almost any other DBMS allows it.

If it really doesn't work, you can do this:

```
select * from table where STR(numberfield) like "*9"
```

**EDIT:** Maybe it didn't work because you used `%` which is used with `*` in Access :

```
select * from table where numberfield like "*9"
```

Comment: Why all this string handling to simulate simple arithmetic?

Comment: @Gustav  Downvote for the correct answer? He didn't ask how to achieve this or what is the best way. He only asked why didn't his query work .

Comment: @sagi: Yes. It's a clumsy method. Indeed when the clean method is right at hand. And you should never refrain from using your privilege to also educate.

Comment: Lets make some things clear: 1. What you call 'clumsy' others may call more understabdable, including me. 2. When someone asks a question, he expect an answer, not an improvment(not that there's anything wrong with improving). My job here is to assist him, not to make his query the best it could ever be. If you hadn't posted an answer of your own, you wouldn't say that.

Comment: The question was clear: _Is there an option to select on the ending when it is a number field?_. The straight solution is to use `Mod`, and I would and did post this as the answer, as the questioneer most likely wasn't aware of this simple method, or he wouldn't have been struggling with string conversation.

Comment: @Gustav There is no problem with using `LIKE` on numerical columns, he just didn't use the correct syntax, no need for convertions. There might be easier ways in terms of performances , but I find it easier to understand `LIKE '%9'` is looking at the last character than `mod 10 = 9` .

Comment: @Gustav What about the case, when your number is 1.09 and you want to include that value too?

Comment: Yes, that would be one of the cases where you would have to use string handling - just like if you wish to display the _fraction_ only of a decimal number where leading zeroes cannot be omitted.

Comment: Then wouldn't you say my answer is more correct ? You were quick to look for flaws in my answer, not in yours. @Gustav

Comment: @sagi: I would say it has a wider coverage as it will handle decimals as well, and I see no "flaws" (don't know where you got that). But with integers, using `Mod` is the optimum as it is 10 times faster than `Str`. The `numberfield` was specified as _numeric_ like `Id`, thus a Long. That could be a false assumption, I know; only the questioneer will know.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are numbers, so use Mod for this:

```
select * from table where numberfield mod 10 = 9
```

Comment: How anyone can downvote this is beyond me. Don't people attend math in school anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting to string and comparing, just extract the rightmost digit with a MOD operation.
Edit your query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE ((([numberfield] Mod 10)=9));
```